# Private/Public RSA 2048 key pair - How to verify RSA PKCS#1v1.5 SHA 256 with phpseclib

Tags: rsa, phpseclib, android-biometric

I need to verify a signature in an api endpoint, but whatever I tried I can't validate it. Data comes from mobile device.

Key pair is created on android through this library and in particular, with these functions.

1. **Key pair** [ReactNativeBiometrics.createKeys](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics?tab=readme-ov-file#createkeys) --> in deep [source code](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/rnbiometrics/ReactNativeBiometrics.java#L97)
2. **Signature** [ReactNativeBiometrics. createSignature](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics?tab=readme-ov-file#createsignatureoptions) --> In deep [source code](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/rnbiometrics/ReactNativeBiometrics.java#L151)

composer.json

```json
{
    "require": {
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^3.0",
        "kint-php/kint": "^4.2"
    }
}
```

index.php

```php
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA\PublicKey;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA;

$message = "CIAO";
$signature = "nu92wNMUDDUgZJbrKOIJt09FOfvMvQ6fWlNCfvkxqhUuGIT7hCnikQCM4KfXJN/X7D3+ISQvu1+BbVYug2uvxDwtDt7mHRr7lo7SRN6/yFq237LJ9iHZNZWXz1Ict1ez92Aa1oeDZtMpO84VOrVE372UNOETFvz+AaeTJ3lO/3WV+xu+uQ36FiOhLtAi7CXFhCki3+P6oO0Va1PtB2rmdiMcbHSkn3y5IZG5UTxLtRYr0dkTbbq+ySNMdYY01Yd1aOHl7phgoR+sRHQwOaq2/IHAahBOTZShrjLy5b/DmDaYwjjAs76FSQFiWtPjtm0WdiroGbzdwsHjWgBXKyHzHA==";

$hash = hash('sha256', $message, true);

$publicKey = "
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAu4sNG1i5Tiqc2nz5nFU8
Q7UaKbOqV2jTCB0Alg2hwT6GQX/GhPTHiPicoLPX1yubPbDxn9e/4ZPCwdfW20JG
4oaGNUnT6VSfH9Tx5ckBGIYzsHbRU7llKgMFK91RVrTCb/3v1sSEHBthby2C4c2V
N1zDCZxaTGfY3zgsEhUIYHhagam1c/WHR9mVCu+9a9QwsMgJ9ppKwikzLyetNkla
MvIKzTxsFHrtZrmBhlbmRHFXGKqqwvnwxkER14YpldiXBFUJ1/p4JHE09byfxmC/
9kRjFxqOxU3hwvO2YlRbk9/T8+6mtyyUxHLLK37vBYOuvKEaPIKM/ASm8UiZLwqq
swIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
";

$key = PublicKeyLoader::loadPublicKey($publicKey, $password = false);

\Kint::dump(
    $publicKey,
    $key::getSupportedKeyFormats(),
    $key->getLoadedFormat(),
    $key->getPadding(),
    (string) $key->getHash(),
    $key,
    $key instanceof \phpseclib3\Crypt\Common\PublicKey,
    $key->verify(base64_decode($message, true), base64_decode($signature, true)),
    $key->verify(base64_decode($message, true), $signature),
    $key->verify($message, base64_decode($signature, true)),
    $key->verify($message, $signature),
    $key->verify($hash, base64_decode($signature, true))
);
```

Result:

[image]

I verified signature with success with this tool online [here](https://8gwifi.org/RSAFunctionality?rsasignverifyfunctions=rsasignverifyfunctions&keysize=2048)

Obviously there is something that I miss, but I can't figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validates fine for me with this code:

```php
$message = "CIAO";
$signature = "nu92wNMUDDUgZJbrKOIJt09FOfvMvQ6fWlNCfvkxqhUuGIT7hCnikQCM4KfXJN/X7D3+ISQvu1+BbVYug2uvxDwtDt7mHRr7lo7SRN6/yFq237LJ9iHZNZWXz1Ict1ez92Aa1oeDZtMpO84VOrVE372UNOETFvz+AaeTJ3lO/3WV+xu+uQ36FiOhLtAi7CXFhCki3+P6oO0Va1PtB2rmdiMcbHSkn3y5IZG5UTxLtRYr0dkTbbq+ySNMdYY01Yd1aOHl7phgoR+sRHQwOaq2/IHAahBOTZShrjLy5b/DmDaYwjjAs76FSQFiWtPjtm0WdiroGbzdwsHjWgBXKyHzHA==";
$publicKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAu4sNG1i5Tiqc2nz5nFU8
Q7UaKbOqV2jTCB0Alg2hwT6GQX/GhPTHiPicoLPX1yubPbDxn9e/4ZPCwdfW20JG
4oaGNUnT6VSfH9Tx5ckBGIYzsHbRU7llKgMFK91RVrTCb/3v1sSEHBthby2C4c2V
N1zDCZxaTGfY3zgsEhUIYHhagam1c/WHR9mVCu+9a9QwsMgJ9ppKwikzLyetNkla
MvIKzTxsFHrtZrmBhlbmRHFXGKqqwvnwxkER14YpldiXBFUJ1/p4JHE09byfxmC/
9kRjFxqOxU3hwvO2YlRbk9/T8+6mtyyUxHLLK37vBYOuvKEaPIKM/ASm8UiZLwqq
swIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";

$signature = base64_decode($signature);
$key = PublicKeyLoader::load($publicKey)->withPadding(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
echo $key->verify($message, $signature) ? 'good' : 'bad';
```

The key thing I'm doing that you're not is `->withPadding(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1)`. `sha256` is the default hash for phpseclib v3 so you don't need to do anything with that. Also, my code cleans up some redundancies in your code.

Comment: I'm a dumb, I tried $key->withPadding(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1) without chaining e without assign it to a new object. I thought it was like a set.
Thank you very much.